# Is there a way to stream an online video to a Raspberry Pi with LCD Display?

Tags: camera, streaming-video, vlc

So my setup is the following:
I have an Raspberry Pi Zero W plus a Camera that Records my Garage 24/7. It is streams the video nonstop so I can access it via Webbrowser. The output is mjpeg.

Is there a way to access that stream and display it on my second raspberry pi 3 on to its LCD display?

I connected the display to the gpio pins and installed the drivers already. Both raspberrys have raspbian lite installed and the raspberry 3 has VLC installed too.

Is there a way to access the stream so I can display it on the lcd display?

Thanks in advance :)

-Paul

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your stream isn't password protected and your second Pi with the LCD attached is a GUI distro, I think you can take the URL from the video and display it via ie. VLC (since you've tagged with VLC):

```sh
vlc [url]
```

You can also open network streams in the VLC UI by going to `Medium` -> `Open network stream (ctrl + n)`.

*(I've tested this approach with this url `https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4`)*

You might have to open dev tools find the absolute url to the stream.